# Django 'not in' querying for related fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to filter on objects that only have related objects with values in a finite set - here's how I tried to write it:

```
trips = Trip.objects\
    .filter(study=study, field_values__field__name='mode', field_values__int_value__in=modes)\
    .exclude(study=study, field_values__field__name='mode', field_values__int_value__not_in=modes)\
    .all()
```

I think this would work, except 'not in' is not a valid operator. Unfortunately, 'not modes' here is an infinite set - it could be any int not in modes, so I can't 'exclude in [not modes].'

How can I write this with a Django query?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter this with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Q

Trip.objects.filter(
    study=study,
    field__values__field__name='mode'
).annotate(
    total_values=Count('field_values')
).filter(
    total_values=Count('field_values', filter=Q(field_values__int_value__in=modes)),
    total_values__gt=0
)
```

Here we thus count the total number of related `field_values` with `name_model`, and the ones where the `int_value` is in the given `modes`. If both are the same, we know that no value exists outside of this.